# Concatenate two fiels into one for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to concatenate two fiels (address and place) into 1 field (location).

I have created the following code in my pins controller:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like, :unlike]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy]
  before_save :set_location


  def set_location
      location = "#{address} #{place}"
      end

...

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "It is only allowed to change the restaurants you have added my yourself." if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image, :name, :address, :place, :postal_code, :telephone_number, :website, :emailadress, :location)
    end
end
```

I get this error message

```
undefined method `before_save' for PinsController:Class
```

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `before_save` hook in your controller instead of the model.
Move this code to your model and it should work.

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_location

  # ...

  def set_location
    self.location = "#{address} #{place}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`before_save` is callback for Models, not for Controllers.

You should do:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_location

  def set_location
    self.location = "#{self.address} #{self.place}"
  end
end
```

Comment: You do not have to call `self` explicitly here.